# Static routes with mismatching subnet do not work on virtualized network interfaces

Tags: network, virtualization

Looks like that virtual interfaces created by Big Sur (and Monterey) do NOT allow static routes that do NOT match the network subnet set on the interface.

My test setup is the following (both systems have IP forwarding enabled):

- VM with Linux Ubuntu with IP 10.0.0.1/24.
- Host system with Big Sur/Monterey with virtual interface set to IP 10.0.0.2/24.

If I add a static route to 192.168.50.0/24 via the VM (`sudo route add -net 192.168.50.0/24 10.0.0.1` executed on the host system) and I try to ping from the host system an IP from that specific subnet, say 192.168.50.10, the resulting ICMP traffic does not reach the VM as I would expect (`tcpdump icmp` shows no ICMP traffic at all).

Any other route to a subnet matching the network assigned to the virtual interface (10.0.0.0 in the above example), works, instead, flawlessly.

Any idea why?

I have tried to adjust the route command to specify the network interface or the MAC address of the interface, but same unfortunately with the same results.

Comment: You're incorrect in your assumption that Big Sur doesn't allow static routes that does not match the network subnet set on the interface. I think you need a bit extra configuration in order to do what you want. It is unclear from the question whether you ran the "sudo route add -net ..." command _inside_ the vm or in the host system.

Comment: That was on the host system. I am updating the post

Comment: Which command on the VM do you use to detect ICMP traffic? (I assume tcpdump, please give full command) - What OS do you run on the VM? (I assume Linux)

Comment: `tcpdump icmp`, and Linux. I am updating the post to add these two details.

Comment: Do you have multiple interfaces in Linux? - If so, use the "-i" option for tcpdump to select the right one. Most probably your problem lies with the VMware setup. Check the network editor in VMware (or just virtual machine Settings) to determine how the interface been setup - for example if you're using a NAT'ed interface, you can't do simple routing like you're trying to here. Instead set your interface to be Bridged.

Comment: Only one interface in Linux. It worked on Catalina and Mojave with NAT'ed interfaces. Stopped working on BigSur.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I am getting the same results with a "Private network" between host and guest.

Comment: Yet another test:
`sudo route add -net 192.168.50.0/24 -interface bridge101`, `ping 192.168.50.5`, and `sudo tcpdump -i bridge101` all ran on the host system, show no ICMP traffic.